# paper-icon-button should call parent element function

Tags: polymer

I have the following pseudo component structure:

```
<polymer-element ...>
    <parent-custom-element>
        <custom-tableview-element data="{{data}}"></custom-tableview-element>
    </parent-custom-element>
    <script>
        ready: function () {
            this.data = [{ actionButtons: [{ icon: "send" , action: this.onSendAction() },
                                           { icon: "delete" , action: this.onDeleteAction() }]
                         },
                         { actionButtons: [{ icon: "add" , action: this.onAddAction() },
                                           { icon: "edit" , action: this.onEditAction() }]]
                        }];
       },    
       onSendAction : function (e, detail, sender) {
           console.log("onSendAction tapped...");
       },
       onDeleteAction : function (e, detail, sender) {
           console.log("onDeleteAction tapped...");
       },
       onAddAction : function (e, detail, sender) {
           console.log("onAddAction tapped...");
       },
       onEditAction : function (e, detail, sender) {
           console.log("onEditAction tapped...");
       },
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Then the `custom-tableview-element` is a `core-list` with a `paper-icon-button` as follow:

```
<polymer-element name="custom-tableview-element">
  <template>
    <core-list id="list" data="{{data}}" selectionEnabled="{{selectionEnabled}}"
      selection="{{selection}}" height="80" flex multi?={{multi}} style="height:400px;">
      <template>
        <paper-icon-button icon="{{model.icon}}"
                           on-tap="{{model.action}}">
      </template>
    </core-list>
  </template>
<script>...</script>
....
```

Is it possible to call the `parent-actions`, (e.g `onSendAction` or `onAddAction`) from this `paper-icon-button`?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to call it directly from inside the element, because it's encapsulated inside shadow dom. But you could try to attach the function to global variable like window.